# Discord bot node.js mssql package

Tags: nodejs, mssql

Soy bastante nuevo en js y venia a ver si me podian ayudar un poco, tengo un bot en discord mediando node.js, discord.js, y he hecho la conexion a una base de datos mssql con el package mssql, mi problema es que quiero que el bot de discord muestre un valor especifico de un field, pero en el chat solo sale [object, Object], alguna idea de como puedo hacer que se vea el valor real?

Codigo:

````
const client = new Discord.Client();
var sql = require('mssql')


var dbconfig = {
   server: "-",
   user: "sa",
   password: "-",
   database: "-",
   port: 1433,
   options: {
      encrypt: false,
      parseJSON: true
   }
};



 client.on("message", message => {
   if(message.content.startsWith("&test")){
   var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
   conn.connect(function (err) {  
   if (err) throw err;
   var req = new sql.Request(conn)
   req.query(req.template`select Usuario FROM Usuarios where nUsuario = '1'`, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      else
      message.channel.send(`${result}`);

  
                     
         conn.close();
   });
 });
};
}); ```


Gracias por su tiempo!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.recordset` es un array donde cada elemento es una fila devuelta por el query.
`result.recordset[0]` es la primera fila, un objeto con cada uno de los campos.

```
let consulta = "select usuario from tUser where nUsuario = '1'";
    req = new sql.Request(conn);

req.query(consulta, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else if (result.recordset.length >= 1) {

        //ACÁ OBTENÉS DE LA PRIMERA FILA --> el valor de la columna usuario

        let nombreDeUsuario = result.recordset[0].usuario;

    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionó 100% muchísimas gracias!!